# How would i get the data from each event from a jsonResult with full calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, razor-pages

I'm attempting to get event data (Title, date,etc) for an event when clicked but I can't figure out a way to do it since I add the data through the JSON result and full calendar javascript. If I cant, is there a better way to allow the backend razorpage to send data to the full calendar javascript?

backend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using DynaHealth.Models;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace TeleHealthB.Pages
{
    public class CalendarModel : PageModel
    {
       
       

        // public IndexModel(TeleHealthB.Models.HealthProjectContext context)
        //{
        //  healthProject = context;
        //}

        [BindProperty]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Doc { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Pat { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string dec { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        
        [BindProperty]
        public JsonResult result { get; set; }


        public string today = DateTime.Today.ToString();

        public void OnGet()
        {

            // result = (JsonResult)OnGetEvents();
        }


        public class eventShow
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string start { get; set; }
            public string end { get; set; }



            //public string description { get; set; }

            // public string patient { get; set; }

            //   public string doctor { get; set; }




        }

        private DynaHealth2Context db;
        public CalendarModel(DynaHealth2Context _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }
        public IActionResult OnGetEvents()
        {
            List<eventShow> events = new List<eventShow>();
            eventShow show = new eventShow();
            try
            {
                string x = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");

                using (var context = new DynaHealth2Context())
                {

                   var query = from st in context.Appointments
                              where st.PatientEmail == x.Trim() || st.ProviderEmail == x.Trim()
                            select st;



                    //   foreach (var item in query.ToList())
                    // {

                    //   show.id = item.Id;
                    //    show.title = item.Title;
                    //   show.description = item.Description;
                    //     show.start = item.Start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    //show.end = item.End.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");


                    //    events.Add(show);
                    // }




                    
                    return new JsonResult(query.ToList());
                }





            }
            catch { return null; }
        }

        

        public IActionResult OnGetADDEvent(string sub)
        {
  //          using (var context = new HealthProjectContext())
            {
                try

                {
                    //context.Schedules.Add(schedule);

                    return null;

                }
                catch { return null; };


            }
        }

      //  public onPost()
      //  {
        //    RedirectToPage("./Meeting");
      //  }

        public IActionResult OnPostRemoveEvent(string sub)
        {
   //         using (var context = new HealthProjectContext())
            {
                try

                {




                    //  context.Schedules.Add(schedule);

                    return null;

                }
                catch { return null; };


            }
        }
    }
}
```

frontend

```
@model TeleHealthB.Pages.CalendarModel
@{



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    
    <head>

        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Calendar</title>
        <link href='~/lib/TestCalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src='~/lib/TestCalendar/main.js'></script>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                    },


                    initialDate: Date.now(),
                    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    selectable: true,
                    selectMirror: true,
                    select: function (arg) {

                        var title = prompt('Reasining For meeting:');

                        if (title) {
                            var tie = prompt('Time');
                        }

                        if (title) {
                            calendar.addEvent({
                                title: title,
                                start: arg.start,
                                Starttime: tie,
                                end: arg.end,
                                EndTime: arg.EndTime
                            })
                        }
                        calendar.unselect()
                    },
                    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {

                        window.open("/Meeting", "_blank");


                        return false
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: "/calendar?handler=events"
                });
                calendar.render();
            });

        </script>
        <style>
            #calendar {
                max-width: 1100px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Schedule View</h1>
        <div id='calendar'></div>

        <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">

                            <span aria-hidden="false">x</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                        </button>

                        <h4 id="modalTItle" class="modal-title"> </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" name="del" class="btn btn-default" id="eventURL">Delete</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventURL" target="_blank">Schedule</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>
    </html>
    }
```

Comment: You're asking how to pass the event details to the /Meeting endpoint, I think? Just pass the ID as a query parameter in the URL, then the server would pull the details out of the database again. Standard web app behaviour

Comment: P.s. `eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) ` is wrong...check the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the event in the backend,you can do following change:

You can use code  `var events = calendar.getEvents();` to get all the events,and then push the property you want in the array,the pass the arry to the backend.

**Frontend**

```
//Add a button to get event:
<button id="GetEvent">Get Event</button>

//....
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },


                initialDate: Date.now(),
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                selectable: true,
                selectMirror: true,
                select: function (arg) {

                    var title = prompt('Reasining For meeting:');

                    if (title) {
                        var tie = prompt('Time');
                    }

                    if (title) {
                        calendar.addEvent({
                            title: title,
                            start: arg.start,
                            Starttime: tie,
                            end: arg.end,
                            EndTime: arg.EndTime
                        })
                    }
                    calendar.unselect()
                },
                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {

                    window.open("/Meeting", "_blank");


                    return false
                },
                editable: false,
                dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: "/calendar?handler=events"
            });
            calendar.render(); 
            //add following
            $("#GetEvent").click(function () {
            var events = calendar.getEvents();
            var e = [];
            $.each(events, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value.start);
                console.log(index);
                var start_time = value.start;
                var end_time = value.end;
                var id = parseInt(value.id);
                var slot = {
                    start: start_time,
                    end: end_time,
                    id: id,
                };
               
                e.push(slot);
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test?handler=getevents',
                contentType:"application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(e),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
            });
        });
    });
```

**Backend:**

```
//add this line
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string Doc { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Pat { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string dec { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    //delete this line
    //[BindProperty]

    public JsonResult result { get; set; }

    public string today = DateTime.Today.ToString();

    public void OnGet()
    {

      JsonResult  result = (JsonResult)OnGetEvents();
    }


    public class eventShow
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string end { get; set; }

    }
    public IActionResult OnGetEvents()
    {
    }
    public void OnPostGetEvents([FromBody]List<eventShow> model)
    {
    }
```

**Test result:**
[image]